# WebStorm does not recognize Sass files imported with usage webpack aliases

Tags: javascript, css, sass, webpack, webstorm

I use webpack 2 with `sass-loader` in my project and I need to import some global Sass files (in my case files with Sass variables) in component style files. I don't want to write relative path for global files, instead of this I want to use absolute path.

i.e. I want to write

```
@import "~styles/variables";
```

instead of

```
@import "../../../variables"
```

For this I use alias for 'styles' directory in my webpack config

```
resolve: {
 ...
  alias: {
    'styles': helpers.root('src/styles'),
  }
}
```

All this works as I expected and webpack compile Sass properly. But WebStorm does not understand import with tilde and underscores this import with error.

I already pointed in WebStorm settings that `src` is my Source Root directory.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hi, having the same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: @AndriiRomanchak I didn't resolve this problem because I have very complicated webpack configuration, but JetBrains teem added webpack config analyzer to WebStorm and it works fine. Look at
https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/06/webstorm-2017-2-eap-172-2827/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such resolving is not currently supported in current versions (2017.1 ATM).

Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

- Sass: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25321
- LESS: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23707
- More generic ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17533 (the base for the first 2 tickets)

Comment: Just updated to version 2017.2.4 and still getting the same error. The links say the problem is fixed

Comment: @AndriiRomanchak Please ask in the appropriate ticket or file new one if you are sure that you have configured all correctly but it still does not work.

Comment: My PHPStorm understands tilde with paths from `node_modules` folder but doesn't understand ones from `src` folder. My `src` is marked as a source root. Could you advise anything?

Comment: @AndriiRomanchak Unfortunately not -- I'm not using webpack at all so have no ideas on what can be done here. You may ask on WebStorm forums though: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367229-WebStorm

Answer (score 3):

The issue was fixed in PHPStorm (probably WebStorm too) since version 2017.2.2.

More info can be found [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/06/webstorm-2017-2-eap-172-2827/) as it was pointed above.

Aliases work fine but in case you are not using `Webpack` (you have an `Angular CLI` project for example) you can create a fake `webpack.config.js` file in the project's root and fill it with appropriate aliases just to make the IDE resolve your files.

Here's the working example:

```
// fake webpack config used only to help make PHPStorm resolve imported .sass files
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,

  // Directory resolution fix
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      sass: "/src/sass"
    }
  }
};
```